# How to get only contacts that has email when using CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm trying to get all the contacts from the device that has a email address. 
Now my code (below) gets all the contacts, what do i have to add to get only contacts with email?

```
final static String SELECTION = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + "<>''" + " AND " + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1";

final static String[] PROJECTION = {
            Contacts._ID, Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY , Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI, SORT_ORDER, Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY
        };    

  new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
          Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
          ContactsQuery.PROJECTION,
          ContactsQuery.SELECTION,
          null,
          Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY);
```

Comment: check this http://androidexample.com/Get_Contact_Emails_By_Content_Provider_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=121&aaid=141

Answer (score -2):

**Try this**

```
public ArrayList<String> getNameEmailDetails(){
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Cursor cur1 = cr.query( 
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                                new String[]{id}, null); 
                while (cur1.moveToNext()) { 
                    //to get the contact names
                    String name=cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.e("Name :", name);
                    String email = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    Log.e("Email", email);
                    if(email!=null){
                        names.add(name);
                    }
                } 
                cur1.close();
            }
        }
        return names;
    }
```

once you got all the contacts from cursor after that you should provide query to get email

```
Cursor cur1 = cr.query( 
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                                    new String[]{id}, null);
```

from cur1 you can get all contacts which have email ID.

Comment: Please have some explanation. Hard coded answers are bound to get down votes

Comment: Thanks, but i need to make a filter in my code, not get all the contacts and then go over them (which is what im doing now)

Comment: @Nabin I have given explanation now, Why down voted?

Comment: can You explain little more what's your requirement? @user733284

Comment: You are asking the requirement after answering?